# QFileDialog: exec() vs show()

Tags: c++, qt

Приветствую! Поясните пожалуйста ситуацию с QFileDialog.
Имеется такой код:

```
m_chooseFolderDialog = new QFileDialog(this);
m_chooseFolderDialog->setFileMode(QFileDialog::Directory);
m_chooseFolderDialog->setOption(QFileDialog::ShowDirsOnly, true);
m_chooseFolderDialog->show();
```

При выполнении выводится окно диалога с стиле Qt, опция QFileDialog::ShowDirsOnly игнорируется. При этом следующий код работает как и задумано:

```
m_chooseFolderDialog = new QFileDialog(this);
m_chooseFolderDialog->setFileMode(QFileDialog::Directory);
m_chooseFolderDialog->setOption(QFileDialog::ShowDirsOnly, true);
m_chooseFolderDialog->exec();
```

Выводится стандартное для платформы окно выбора директорий, видимы только папки. 
С чем связано такое поведение и какой из методов будет правильнее использовать?

Comment: Обратите внимание, что `show` унаследован от `QWidget`, а `exec` от `QDialog`. Логично будет предположить что в методе `exec` выполняются действия специфичные для диалога.

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb спасибо, очень похоже на правду, жаль в документации это не освещено ясно.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Так происходит потому, что при создании [`QFileDialog`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html), он старается показать диалог от платформы, если она имеет таковой:

> **By default, a platform-native file dialog will be used if the platform
>   has one**. In that case, the widgets which would otherwise be used to
>   construct the dialog will not be instantiated, so related accessors
>   such as layout() and itemDelegate() will return null. You can set the
>   DontUseNativeDialog option to ensure that the widget-based
>   implementation will be used instead of the native dialog.

Происходит это за счёт того, что в [`exec`](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/dialogs/qdialog.cpp.html#_ZN7QDialog4execEv) функции выполняется как `show`, так и особая обработка, которая, в случае наличия платформенного диалога,— создаёт его. Но функция `show` не переопределена в `QDialog`, а это значит, что выполняется стандартное для `QWidget` поведение: мы просто делаем `QWidget` видимым. Отсюда и различие. Почему этого нет в документации? Я не знаю.

Answer (score 0):

Из [документации](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#exec) к `QDialog`:

> `exec`: Shows the dialog as a modal dialog, blocking until the user closes it. The function returns a DialogCode result.
>
> If the dialog is application modal, users cannot interact with any other window in the same application until they close the dialog. If the dialog is window modal, only interaction with the parent window is blocked while the dialog is open. By default, the dialog is application modal.

Т.е. эта функция не только выводит диалог, но также блокирует до закрытия либо все приложение, либо родительский виджет - в зависимости от настроек модальности. Метод `show()` такого функционала не несёт.

*Update*: По поводу различий в отображении `QFileDialog::ShowDirsOnly` в документации ничего не указано. Возможно, это баг в библиотеке, либо недочет в документации.

Comment: Спасибо, эту часть документации я сразу же прочел, но к сожалению там нет ни слова о разнице в работе с учетом опций и не объясняется, почему при show() к диалогу не применяется визуальный стиль платформы.

Comment: @Wickedwannabe Либо это ошибка Qt, либо авторы документации забыли указать, что метод `show` правильным образом работать не будет. В любом случае, в примерах используется именно `exec`, т.ч. вероятнее всего второй вариант, и `show` лучше просто не использовать.